# How to remove undesired line and add the desired one in a table?

Tags: tables, formatting

I have a table as below:-

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|l | c | c | c |}
\hline
& & 1 & 2 \\
\hline

\multirow{2}{*}{$abc$} & def & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{klm}} 

\\
\cline{2-2}
& ghi & \\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

However, I want to remove the line below "klm" and add line at the right of "klm". How can I do that?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on row 2 you want

```
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{...}
```

to re-insert the vertical rule. Similarly on row 3 you want an (empty) two column entry that re-inserts a rule so

```
& ghi & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}\\
```

Comment: Thanks, I replaced those 2 lines by `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{klm}}` and `& ghi & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\` and got it done!